# How can I return a list in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I am working through Programming Elixir book and playing with exercises.  I have a sum function where I would like to return sum value in a list `[]` instead of just a number but I get `bad argument in arithmetic expression`.  Could do with some directions?

```
defmodule Mymod do
  def sum([]), do: []
  def sum([head | tail]) do
    [head  + sum(tail)]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Mymod.sum/1` returns a list and you are trying to add it to the number.

To make it work, you should “unveil” the list returned by `sum` into the number and then add it:

```
defmodule Mymod do
  def sum([]), do: []
  def sum([head | tail]) do
    case sum(tail) do
      []  -> [head]
      [s] -> [head + s]
    end
  end
end

IO.inspect Mymod.sum([5, 6, 7])
#⇒ [18]
```

The tail-recursive variant would look like (inspired by the answer by @theanh-le):

```
defmodule Mymod do
  def sum(list, acc \\ 0)

  def sum([], 0), do: []
  def sum([], acc), do: [acc]
  def sum([head | tail], acc) do
    sum(tail, head + acc)
  end
end

IO.inspect Mymod.sum([5, 6, 7])
#⇒ [18]
```

Comment: Upvoted for the first line of answer which highlights the exact issue.

Comment: You are supposed to choose the correct answer (if any) and mark it with greeny, BTW.

Comment: Will do, but still trying to figure out a way without using accumulator.

Comment: 1. Why would you try to omit accumulator? It is the very (I’d say most) common practice in FP. 2. There is no way to use tail recursion without an accumulator; whether you do not want to use TR (lists are deterministically relatively small,) just pick up the former snippet from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way you can use `tail recursive` to do this make your code much prettier:

```
defmodule MyMod do
  def sum([]), do: []
  def sum(list) do
    do_sum(0, list)
  end

  defp do_sum(current_sum, []), do:[current_sum] 
  defp do_sum(current_sum, [head | tail]) do
    new_sum = current_sum + head
    do_sum(new_sum, tail)
  end
end
```

iex:

```
iex()> MyMod.sum([5,6,7])
[18]
```

Comment: Upvoted for tail recursion; this answer has one glitch: it returns unexpected `[0]` for empty list, while OP returned an empty list. Additional `defp do_sum(0, []), do:[]` is likely required.

Comment: Right.I forgot.Thanks a lot